# generate video pixel by pixel, programmatically

Tags: python, ruby, video, animation

I'd like to generate an animation pixel by pixel programmatically. Preferably in Hi-Def, in Python or in Ruby. I thought about using PIL to make each frame and then convert the frames into video. Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: Clarification, this is 2D and I need the pixels to be precise.

EDITEDIT:

Something like this:

```
frame = Frame()
frame.draw(0, 0, 'red')
frame.draw(0, 1, 'blue')
...
frame = Frame()
...
```

Would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rcairo - ruby bindings for Cairo image library.

https://github.com/rcairo/rcairo

Answer (score 3):

checkout [VPython](http://www.vpython.org/). Its pretty easy and can do what you are looking for.

Comment: Is there any sort of example code you could provide or link to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffmpeg, passe to it a rowvideo (frames), and converte it to a compressed video format like mp4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).